# How to take a string from a user and store it in a character array of size 10

Tags: visual-c++

Below is my code. I'm trying to write a program that takes a string from a user and stores it in a character array of size 10. I´d like to display a substring of count letters from the left, where count is given by the user and print an appropriate message if the user enters a string that is out of range by count.

But my code throws a CRT memory allocation error and now "LNK1168".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JliTA.png)

How can I fix this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

       void Destructor(char *p)// function 
       {
       int i = 0;

       cout << "Showing the substring .. " << p << endl << endl;;



      }

      char* left(const char* target, const int count)
     {
       char* ptr = NULL;// initialization of pointer 

       ptr = new char[count];// allocating dynaic memory ..

       cout << ptr << endl << endl;

       if (count > 10)
      {
        cout << " Input is out of range " << endl;
      }

     else
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
          {
            ptr[i] = target[i];
            cout << ptr[i] << endl;
            if (i == count - 1)
            {
                ptr[i + 1] = '\0';
                break;
                }
         }
          cout << ptr << endl;

          Destructor(ptr);//function call ....
      }


    return ptr;
}

void main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int count = 0;
    char* ptr = NULL;
    string userInput;
    char arr[SIZE] = { '\0' };

    ptr = arr;

    cout << "Please Enter a string :-";
    getline(cin, userInput);

    for (int i = 0; i <SIZE; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = userInput[i];
        cout << "COUNT " << i << endl;
        if (i == SIZE - 1)
        {
            ptr[i + 1] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        if (userInput[i] == '\0')
            break;
    /*if (i == 9)
        break;*/
    }


    cout << "Checking character array in main .. " << ptr << endl;

     cout << "Enter a substring count : ";
     cin >> count;

     ptr = left(ptr, count);// function call...


     delete ptr;//deleting new memory ...
 }
```

Comment: `arr[SIZE]` contains `SIZE` elements, numbered 0 through `SIZE-1`. Your program writes to `arr[SIZE]`, whereupon it exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun. Specifically, here: `if (i == SIZE - 1) ptr[i + 1] = '\0';`

Comment: `ptr = new char[count]; cout << ptr` Since the memory that `ptr` points to is uninitialized, this prints random garbage, quite possibly causing a buffer overrun.

Comment: Same buffer overrun here: `if (i == count - 1) ptr[i + 1] = '\0';` Valid indexes into `ptr` are 0 through `count-1`. You are writing to `ptr[count]`. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: Oh my bad ! I didn't see that's happening . Thank you so much ! :)